# ziplock-type gallon bag to store my sour dough starter in the fridge.

Tags: bread

I am using  a  zip type gallon bag to store my sour dough starter in the fridge.  Will it keep working after a week  in storage? I take it out of the fridge the night before and feed it two cups flour and two cups lukewarm water.

Comment: Not sure you need to use up that much storage space.  For example, I keep about 1/4 cup in fridge storage.  I try to feed weekly, sometimes I forget and several weeks pass.  It has never failed.

Comment: @moscafj there are recipes where you make about half the bread volume or more out of starter, so if the OP is baking large loaves, this can be needed. Also, a gallon bag doesn't have to be full to the brim.

Answer (score 2):

One week is fine. I keep my starter also for one week in the fridge and feed it once a week:

- 20g starter
- 50g water
- 50g rye flour

If you want to do it for a longer period, I'd exchange the plastic for glass which is 100% safe from leeching nasty stuff into your starter.